# Get full URL of WP plugin admin page

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

I'd like to append an admin notice to the edit page of a particular 3rd party plugin to help prevent user error.

The URL is .../wp-admin/admin.php?page=plugin-name&action=edit...

As $pagenow only returns admin.php and the get_current_screen value for action returns "", how can I identify the full URL to effectively as if page="xx" and action = "yy"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts           = parse_url( admin_url() );
$url             = "{$parts['scheme']}://{$parts['host']}" . add_query_arg( NULL, NULL );
```